# How call multiple requests with Axios and concatenate the answer using an array of URLs

Tags: axios

I have the following code:

```
var pagina 
var array_de_urls=[]

for (pagina=1; pagina <= self.state.numero_de_paginas; pagina++) {
    array_de_urls.push(Constantes.URL_PREFIX + '/courses/'+course_id+'/enrollments?role[]=StudentEnrollment&state[]=active&per_page='+Constantes.PER_PAGE_VALUE+'&page='+pagina)
}
```

After the code runs, the "array_de_urls" parameter got 13 URLs inside of it.

Then I run this piece of code

```
array_de_urls.forEach(url => {
  axios.get( url, config
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log("getAlunosArray chamado axios")

    var joined = self.state.array_aluno.concat(response.data);
    self.setState({ array_aluno: joined })
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error array_de_urls: "+error)
  });    
});
```

I was able to concatenate all results inside the "array_aluno" state parameter.

But now I want to try a different approach.

I want to create an async function that returns the value without using a "state" parameter.

I try to run the code below:

```
var pagina 
var array_de_urls=[]
for (pagina=1; pagina <= self.state.numero_de_paginas; pagina++) {
    array_de_urls.push(Constantes.URL_PREFIX + '/courses/'+course_id+'/enrollments?role[]=StudentEnrollment&state[]=active&per_page='+Constantes.PER_PAGE_VALUE+'&page='+pagina)
}
let response = []
for (let i = 0; i < array_de_urls.length; i++) {
    response.concat( await axios.get( array_de_urls[i], config ) );
}
return response.data
```

But I got an "undefined" object from that code.

How can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a function to resolve my problem.

```
export async function getAlunoArrayAsync(config, course_id, self)  {
  console.log("getAlunoArrayAsync chamado")
  var pagina 
  var array_de_urls=[]
  for (pagina=1; pagina <= self.state.numero_de_paginas; pagina++) {
    array_de_urls.push(Constantes.URL_PREFIX + '/courses/'+course_id+'/enrollments?role[]=StudentEnrollment&state[]=active&per_page='+Constantes.PER_PAGE_VALUE+'&page='+pagina)
  }
  var merged = [];  
  await axios.all( array_de_urls.map(l => axios.get(l, config)) )
  .then(res => {
    merged = [].concat(res)
  })
  let concatenated = []
  for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    // console.log("merged merged[i].data")
    // console.log(merged[i].data.length)
    for (let j = 0; j < merged[i].data.length; j++) {
        //console.log("merged merged[i][j].data: "+j)
        //console.log(merged[i].data[j])
        concatenated.push( merged[i].data[j] )
    }
  }
  return concatenated
}
```